# Finding new entries in a MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql, search

Is it possible to find out if new entries where made into a MySQL table?

For example a table has 10 records and someone adds 2 new.

How do I write a php line to detect the new records (only) and insert them into another table?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please don't sign your posts and write tags in titles.

Comment: what's the point in copying records from table to table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use triggers to achive this.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html

Syntax will be similar to this one:

```
CREATE TRIGGER ins_table AFTER INSERT ON first_table 
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    INSERT INTO second_table values(NEW.field1, NEW.field2,..., NEW.fieldn)
END;
```

Answer (score 3):

New is relative. So logically you need some anchor/baseline to determine what new means in your system.

A few ideas:

- table has a column 'processes' with a default value of 0, everything which has 0 is new
- table has some time entry, new is when it's younger than time t
- table has a relationship with that other table you mention, every entry in the first table that doesn't have an entry in the second table is new.
- new could also mean the last X autoincrement values.

So you see, in order to get a more precise answer you would need to give more information about what exactly it is that you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to implement some sort of control mechanism for this, for example add a column to your table called (as a crude example) `added_into_other_table`. Then check in your query for all records that have a value of zero for `added_into_other_table`. Add only these to the new table, then update your original table to set `added_into_other_table` to 1 for all of the records you just processed so they won't be processed again.